# post data to php in jquery sortable menu

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to use this https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable sortable menu but i have no ideea how to post the data to php so I can update the order in the database
it returns array(0) {} for _POST dump

```
$('.dd').nestable();

$('.dd').on('change', function() {
var data = $('.dd').nestable('serialize');
 ajaxx(data);
});

function ajaxx(data){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url:'page.php', 
        data: data, 
       success: function(data){
        $("#response").html(data);
       }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you the AJAX call like this it would work (I haven't test it):

```
$('.dd').nestable();

$('.dd').on('change', function() {
var data = $('.dd').nestable('serialize');
 ajaxx(data);
});

function ajaxx(data){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url:'page.php', 
        data: {
            new_order: data
        }, 
       success: function(data){
        $("#response").html(data);
       }
    });
}
```

Include *data* var in an object: `new_order: data`

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, would probbably work but I went with jQuery $.post in stead.

Comment: Yes, it's another posibility ;)

Comment: got another question if you got time :)

Comment: This one - [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207855/sidebar-menu-add-class-and-toggle-if-url-matches)